# Consuming getstream.io in iOS app but documentation is not enough

Tags: ios, swift, getstream-io

I just want to implement only **get** stuff from getstream.io in iOS application

```
Client.config = .init(apiKey: "<KEY>", appId: "<ID>", token: "<TOKEN>")
```

after writing this line of code

```
let timeline = Client.shared.flatFeed(feedSlug: "timeline", userId: "34")
timeline.get { (response) in
    log(response)
}
```

I am getting 403

Basically I want to get timeline from getstream but I am not able to understand what is token in this case?

Comment: Check [this documentation](https://getstream.github.io/stream-swift/Typealiases.html#/s:9GetStream5Tokena)

Comment: Thanks @Kamran I've already checked this documentation, but my question is what detail should be in token? I've tried so many ways still getting 403

Comment: No detail, just a unique token string generated from the service.

Comment: I did that. still getting 403 :(

Answer (score 0):

you need to generate your auth token serverside and pass that back to the iOS client.

Comment: I have generated so many token with different details, but still getting 403. What should be in JWT token when generating?

Comment: @MuhammadRaza only user_id